# create android cards with fragments

Tags: android, android-layout, android-fragments, android-activity

I am new to android and I am working on a project that contains something similar to a news feed. My plan is to get information from a database display it on a card. I just discovered fragments and thought they would be a great way to do this. My question is can I design a fragment as a default card and change info on the general card to the info I get from the database and add the card on to the screen while the app is running?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes you can.
Fragment is a lightweight activity, it's held and hosted by activity and manage it's own UI and interaction. According to your description, the card seems very simple, so my suggestion is using a View.

Comment: How would I go about adding several cards (using one fragment as a template) to the screen while the app is running? Also, I plan on when a card is pressed, changing the screen to show more detailed info about the card, so if I add multiple cards can each one have an id that I set?

Comment: You use fragment manager to manage its fragments. If your card is just showing some information, use view instead of fragment. You can arrange these card view into GridView or other suitable container, and setup listener to handle touch event. Use another fragment to present detailed card information.